# Query by Id in MongoTemplate Fails Due to Conversion to $oid

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a simple operation to remove a document from MongoDB using MongoTemplate. The reason for using MongoTemplate is because the project is not directly associated with the service utilizing the database, hence it does not require, and should not require, the database model classes itself.

The query is as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id")
        .is(new ObjectId(id));
      mongoTemplate.remove(Query.query(criteria), collectionName);
```

Where `id` is a String object, and `collectionName` is the name of the collection.

However, the query, when translated to MongoDB syntax by Spring Data MongoDB, produces such expression:
`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5e206994943f3c1d6c778efb"}}` instead of `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e206994943f3c1d6c778efb")}`.

As a result, the data persists in the database, even though it should be removed. When I try the former query on Mongo shell itself, it throws the error of `Unknown operator: $oid`.

Is there anything wrong that I did? How to fix them?

Thank you.

Comment: It clearly says that Unknown operator: $oid.

Comment: But the conversion itself was automatically done, and I do not know how to pass the proper query instead of the query using $oid. Have you experienced this kind of problem before @ArpitJain?

Comment: What are the values in the `id` variable _and_ the `_id` field?

Comment: The log output of SpringData MongoDB is not in Mongo Shell format and cannot be directly used there. `$oid` is a valid representation that results from the [extended json](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to fix this by using MongoDatabase instead. By using the method `deleteOne` I was able to delete by `_id` with creating `new ObjectId(id)`, wrapped under `BasicDBObject`.

Answer (score 1):

From Spring Data mongodb 2.2.X @Id operator changed with @MongoId operator.

I used like this and resolved.

Mongodb collection data :

```
_id: ObjectId('5e1f1bf501eb6332ebf8664c')
```

Spring data solution:

```
@MongoId(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
private String id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:
custom a class extends MappingMongoConverter,
and overwrite method **convertId(Object id, Class<?> targetType)**.
like this:

```java
@Override
    public Object convertId(Object id, Class<?> targetType) {
        if (id == null || ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(targetType, id)) {
            return id;
        }

        if (ClassUtils.isAssignable(ObjectId.class, targetType)) {

            if (id instanceof String) {

                if (ObjectId.isValid(id.toString())) {
                    return id.toString();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getConversionService().canConvert(id.getClass(), targetType)
                    ? getConversionService().convert(id, targetType)
                    : convertToMongoType(id, null);
        } catch (ConversionException o_O) {
            return convertToMongoType(id, null);
        }
    }
```